# This package is incompatible

Tags: macos, driver, macos-big-sur

I'm having a issue with my MacOs version, Big Sur, when I want install a device driver. Precisely, a Genius MousePen i608X. My os say:

> This package is incompatible The package is trying to install content
> to the system volume. Contact the software manufacturer for
> assistance.
> Blockquote

The manufacturer doesn't developed a new driver, so I need install this version.

Can you say me how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Sorry, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official FAQ](https://us.geniusnet.com/supports/mousepen-i608x#faq25) for the Genius MousePen i608X, the Mac driver only supports macOS "Sierra" 10.12 and previous versions:

[image]

so, unfortunately, you won't be able to install the driver in Big Sur or any recent (that is, supported) macOS version.

Since the manufacturer supports Windows 10:

[image]

you could either use [Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/guide/bootcamp-assistant/welcome/mac) to install Windows 10 on your Mac, or create a virtual machine using [VMware Fusion](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion.html), [Parallels Desktop](https://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) or [VirtualBox](https://www.oracle.com/virtualization/technologies/vm/downloads/virtualbox-downloads.html). The downside is that you will have to purchase the software you use with the MousePen for Windows, so you may be better off buying a new one.